# Question about the $\ln$ of a product of primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, logarithms

For what conditions of $s\in\mathbb{C}$ does this hold?

1. $$\ln\left[\prod_{\text{p}\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{1-\text{p}^{-s}}\right]=\sum_{\text{p}\in\mathbb{P}}\ln\left[\frac{1}{1-\text{p}^{-s}}\right]$$
2. $$\ln\left[\frac{1}{1-\text{p}^{-s}}\right]=-\ln\left(1-\text{p}^{-s}\right)$$

I dont know where to start.

But what I did was:

- $$\text{p}^s=\text{p}^{\Re(s)+\Im(s)i}=\text{p}^{\Re(s)}\cos\left(\Im(s)\ln(\text{p})\right)+\text{p}^{\Re(s)}\sin\left(\Im(s)\ln(\text{p})\right)i$$
- $$\text{p}^{-s}=\frac{1}{\text{p}^s}=\frac{1}{\text{p}^{\Re(s)+\Im(s)i}}=\text{p}^{-\Re(s)}\cos\left(\Im(s)\ln(\text{p})\right)+\text{p}^{-\Re(s)}\sin\left(\Im(s)\ln(\text{p})\right)i$$

Comment: The first example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples

Comment: @SimpleArt I'm looking for the conditions of the number $s$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula Perhaps $\Re(s)>1$?

Comment: I know that relation with the Riemann zeta function, but I want to know for what conditions the relations hold?

Comment: first you need to make sure, that your product is converging, for this check out SimpleArt's links

Comment: So, ok. The product converges when $\Re(s)>1$, but for what $\Im(s)$ is the identity valid?

Comment: @Popiru Maybe you should be more precise about which branch cut of $\ln$ you mean to use.

Comment: maybe you should first consider a special case where $s\in\mathbb R$ with $s>1$...have you tried this?